# Why am I getting this error (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split') while site is running very well?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm learning Django for the couple of months. At present I'm working on a demo project which is about teachers. After working some days I can't move for the limitation of my programming knowledge. Suddenly I discovered that there is an Error (**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'**) on the console but I can't figure out when it happened. Though my site is running very well with the development server but this problem is also running in the background. I'm using Django 2.2.4 python 3.6, and Postgresql 11.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. Can you guys please help me to get rid of this problem? Thanks in advance!

I have searched on the web for the solution but could not find out any proper solution. Please guys check the error bellow.

```
python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 04, 2019 - 16:28:55
Django version 2.2.4, using settings 'teacher_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[04/Sep/2019 16:31:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6092
[04/Sep/2019 16:31:05] "GET /static/css/all_pass.css HTTP/1.1" 200 17
[04/Sep/2019 16:31:05] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 12488
[04/Sep/2019 16:31:05] "GET /static/css/navbar.css HTTP/1.1" 200 567
[04/Sep/2019 16:31:05] "GET /static/css/font.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5483
[04/Sep/2019 16:31:05] "GET /static/img/headshot.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 27864
[04/Sep/2019 16:31:06] "GET /static/font/SolaimanLipi.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 96104
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[04/Sep/2019 16:31:06] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2509
[04/Sep/2019 16:31:21] "GET /media/videos/2019/09/03/Introduction_to_Calculus_1_of_2-_Seeing_the_big_picture.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 11124736
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
[04/Sep/2019 16:31:21] "GET /media/videos/2019/09/03/Introduction_to_Calculus_1_of_2-_Seeing_the_big_picture.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 49666)
[04/Sep/2019 16:31:21] "GET /media/videos/2019/09/03/Addition_of_Numbers_with_Carrying_-_Maths_For_Class_2_-_Maths_Basics_F_DvzezAP.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 10665984
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
[04/Sep/2019 16:31:21] "GET /media/videos/2019/09/03/Addition_of_Numbers_with_Carrying_-_Maths_For_Class_2_-_Maths_Basics_F_DvzezAP.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 49664)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/home/coduser/Desktop/teacher/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
[04/Sep/2019 16:31:21] "GET /media/videos/2019/09/03/Algebra_Basics-_What_Is_Algebra_-_Math_Antics.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 11190272
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/coduser/Desktop/teacher/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/coduser/Desktop/teacher/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
  File "/home/coduser/Desktop/teacher/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
Traceback (most recent call last):
----------------------------------------
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
[04/Sep/2019 16:31:21] "GET /media/videos/2019/09/03/Algebra_Basics-_What_Is_Algebra_-_Math_Antics.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 49658)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/coduser/Desktop/teacher/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
  File "/home/coduser/Desktop/teacher/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
  File "/home/coduser/Desktop/teacher/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/home/coduser/Desktop/teacher/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/home/coduser/Desktop/teacher/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
----------------------------------------
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/coduser/Desktop/teacher/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/coduser/Desktop/teacher/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/home/coduser/Desktop/teacher/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
```

**HTML code for the embedded video**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}



<a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content">Skip to content</a>

<!-- <div class="badge"></div> -->

<main id="content" class="main-area">

    {% for post in posts %}
    <section class="main-content">
        <div class="teacher-student">
            <div class="teacher">
                <img src="{% static 'img/headshot.jpg' %}" alt="">
                <!-- <p>TEACHER</p> -->
                <a href="user_profile.html">{{ post.author.get_full_name }}</a>
                <small>{{ post.publish }}</small>
            </div>
            <div class="available">
                {% if post.is_available %}                    
                        <a href="#">Teacher Available</a>
                {% endif %}                
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="main-article">
            <a href="detail.html">
                <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
            </a>
            <video playsinline oncontextmenu="return false;" controls preload="metadata" controlsList="nodownload"
                disablePictureInPicture src="{{ post.clip.url}}" type='video/mp4'>

            </video>

            <article>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Asperiores magni eveniet
                    praesentium esse molestias iusto doloremque ducimus nobis ex hic. Natus, ipsum...
                </p>
            </article>
            <div class="total-like-share">
                <p class="like"><span>Like 400</span></p>
                <p class="share"><span>Comments 4000</span></p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
    {% endfor %}

</main>


<!-- Left Side Bar -->
<aside class="sidebar-left">
    <div class="left-sidebar">
        <h2 class="left-sidebar-title">Result Board</h2>
        <div class="updates-contens">
            <p><a href="#">Recent Results</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Old Results</a></p>            
        </div>
    </div>


</aside>

<!-- Right Side Bar -->
<aside class="sidebar-right">
    <div class="right-sidebar">
        <h2 class="right-sidebar-title">Post Updates</h2>
        <div class="updates-contens">
            <p><a href="#">Latest Posts</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Most comented posts</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Most shared posts</a></p>
        </div>

    </div>
</aside>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: This always seems to happen when your server is sending a video to your client. Is this a large video? Can you check in your browser dev tools, network tab, the corresponding request/response? What do you see there?

Comment: @dirkgroten okay dear. Length of the video varies on each post( i.e: 10 mins, 12 mins, 5 mins).  I'm checking what you said and soon come back to you. Thanks a lot for your prompt help.

Comment: @dirkgroten 
[Could you please check the link for the screen shot of network tab? I'm just a novice, so it is difficult to read the request/response](https://ibb.co/k0X6m6x)

Comment: nothing strange in this one, status code is 200. Can you enable the "preserve log" button, click the "delete" button (the crossed circle next to the red dot) and refresh your page. Look then if you see the videos duplicated.

Comment: @dirkgroten [After enabling the preserve log button and executing the action for delete button, please check this screen shot](https://ibb.co/FXfMgxN)

Comment: ok, you can disable the preserve log now. I don't understand the size component of your videos, they clearly aren't 220B or 64kB. How are you actually embedding them in your page? Note that this might not be a huge issue, you'll be serving your videos in an entirely different way on production (not with the django server) so I think this is only related to the large videos. For example, I haven't been able to serve large videos on my local machine that auto-play in some browsers (e.g. Safari), but I was able to serve them fine with nginx on production.

Comment: @dirkgroten You are always rocking dear. Three videos are serving now and their size all together still not crossing 100MB. The information you have given now is enough for a solution I think. And I assume when I will use production server with nginx I can upload thousands of videos and hope they will not cause any problem like it's happening now. Thank you very much dear.

Comment: If this is going to be a video site, and you are going to serve such large videos (but not all at the same time on one page I suppose), you will run into lots of issues. It's **very very difficult** to build sites that serve videos at scale. That's why the likes of Vimeo, Brightcove and YouTube exist and why people embed videos from these sites in their site rather than hosting them themselves. Normally, videos are streamed, not downloaded. If you think your scale won't be that big, make at least sure you use a CDN in production. Don't make your nginx server serve the videos to the end-users.

Comment: When I said you shouldn’t have this problem in production, I was thinking about a couple of static videos. Not about your users uploading thousands of videos.

Comment: @dirkgroten I have added the HTML code for you if you just look at them. This site is supposed to server thousands of videos without using any third party embedded video service like you mentioned Youtube, Vimeo and so on. It's a nice suggestion you have made to use CDN to serve the video content. This site will be dynamic so that users can upload their own videos here. I can understand it is very difficult. You are very experienced, and you know much much better then me. I will abide by your advice.